# Change controller in container at run time

Tags: ios6, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

So, I have a view container in my iPad app. Based on a selection the user makes, the view in the container needs to change. How is this done? Can I link several view controllers to the same container in Interface builder and then just trigger the segue  to get them to change?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't find correct solution for this problem, but have a look at [this link](http://sandmoose.com/post/35714028270/storyboards-with-custom-container-view-controllers).

What it basically does is creating in-between view controller which is triggered with embed segue. And this view controller is then connected with custom segues to destination view controllers and is responsible for presenting them.

So the answer is that you can not link several view controllers to the same container in Interface builder and then just trigger the segue to get them to change. But this is closest workaround that I have found.